# Avoid repetitions with a loop on a Android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an app where I randomize 5 different integers (first one will generate after launching the activity, the other 4 will after pressing a button) to use them as ID to fetch results from a SQLite DB.

The problem is I don't want those numbers to be repeated so I made an array and a loop to avoid this but it doesn't work as intended, in fact it does nothing. The code looks like this:

```
int[] repeatArray = new int[5];
Integer contRep=0;
Integer myInt=0;

randomizeData();

if(contRep==0){
    repeatArray[0]=myInt;
}else{
for (int i=0;i<repeatArray.length;i++){
    while(myInt==repeatArray[i]){
        randomizeData();
                }
            }
        repeatArray[contRep]=myInt;
        }
contRep++;

public void randomizeData(){
        myInt = r.nextInt(27 - 1) + 1;
}
```

The first one is already created so whenever I press the button `contRep` is 1, and the first number had already been saved in that array. Note that whenever I push the button it executes the code from above. I think the loop works fine but I still sometimes get duplicates. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just select 5 random records from your DB?

Answer (score 0):

> You have to maintain an array of the random numbers generated before say `ArrayOfPreviousNumbers`; so that you can cross check, if newly and randomly generated number is already been there in `ArrayOfPreviousNumbers` or not?

Generate random numbers within the range [20, 80], use

```
final int random = new Random().nextInt(61) + 20; // [0, 60] + 20 => [20, 80]
```

To check if random is already generated or not look up it in `ArrayOfPreviousNumbers` with : `contains`